# First Order Differential Example

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I can't find my mistake , I don't know if I solved it right because wolfram shows me another answer.

$y' + \frac{x^2-y^2}{2xy} = 0$ and $y' + \frac{x}{2y} - \frac{y}{2x} = 0$

$$Substitution$$
$$u=\frac{y}{x}$$
$$xu'+u=y'$$
$$xu'+u + \frac{1}{2u}-\frac{u}{2}=0$$
$$xu'=\frac{u^2-1}{2u}$$
$$x\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{u^2-1}{2u}$$
$$\frac{2u}{u^2-1}du = \frac{1}{x}dx$$

Then I took integral of both sides:
k is constant

$$ln|u^2-1|=ln|x| + k$$

I'm not sure if I can do this let $k_2 = ln|k|$

$$ln|u^2-1|=ln|x| + ln|k_2|$$
$$e^{ln|xk_2|} = u^2 - 1$$
$$|xk_2| = u^2 - 1$$
Again , I'm not sure if I can just throw the modulo away from my $|xk_2|$
$$xk_2 + 1=\frac{y^2}{x^2}$$
$$x^2*(xk_2 + 1) = y^2$$

Please help me to find my mistakes

Result from Wolfram : $y(x) = -\sqrt{c_1 x-x^2}$ and $y(x) = \sqrt{c_1 x-x^2}$.

Comment: As you nicely say, " throw the modulo away" and solve for $u$ first and you will be done. Cheers  :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Cheers , toda :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was in your step going from
$$
xu' + u +\frac{1}{2u} -\frac{u}{2}
$$
To your next step.
So you should get
$$
xu' = -\frac{u^2+1}{2u}
$$

$$
\int \frac{2u}{1+u^2}du = \ln|1+u^2| = -\ln |x| + c
$$
Thus
$$
1+u^2 = \frac{c_1}{x}\\
1 +\frac{y^2}{x^2} = \frac{c_1}{x}
$$
Or
$$
y^2 = c_1x -x^2
$$

Comment: damn it .... that - , thank you

Answer (score 1):

On the third line, it looks like you're getting $$u + \frac{1}{2u}-\frac{u}{2} = \frac{1-u^2}{2u}$$

When it's

$$\begin{align}&\quad \quad u + \frac{1}{2u}-\frac{u}{2} = \\ &= \frac{2u^2}{2u} + \frac{1}{2u} - \frac{u^2}{2u} \\ &=\frac{u^2+1}{2u}\end{align}$$

See what you solution get with this. As for the absolute value, note that your final equation $$\cdots = \frac1x\,dx$$
has a singularity at $x = 0$. This means your solutions can never cross $\{x = 0\}$, and you will have two sets of these: one for positive $x$, and one for negative $x$. Consider both cases seperately if you aren't comfortable with "throwing away" the absolute value.